# linux thread suspended by real-time signal when running in eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, gdb, pthreads, signals

A simple linux multi-thread program.
In one of the threads, i start a timer,and the timer will send SIGRTMIN to to this thread.

when debug with eclipse gdb, the thread will always be suspended by SIGRTMIN,after resume, the program goes well.

out of eclipse gdb,everything goes well.
Anybody can help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

problem solved.
create a .gdbinit file in home directory.
and add the folloing line

```
handle SIG34 nostop noprint pass
```

this makes gdb ignore SIG-xx real-time signals

Comment: So what's the issue? gdb default settings?